# JDBC error: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot submit empty query

Tags: sql, jdbc

I am trying to query the database using JDBC and using the following commands

```
CallableStatement call_state =null;
call_state =con.prepareCall("UPDATE district SET d_next_o_id = ?+1 WHERE d_id = ? AND d_w_id = ?");
call_state.setInt(1, d_next_o_id);
call_state.setInt(2, d_id);
call_state.setInt(3, d_w_id);           
rs=call_state.executeQuery();`
```

I got an exception: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot submit empty query.

Comment: Try using a `PreparedStatement` instead of a `CallableStatement`.

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` and `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()`. An `update` statement does not return a `ResultSet`

Comment: `CallableStatement` is used to call procedures and functions, not to run queries. Follow the advice from the previous comments and use `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though [`CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) (CS) is the "interface used to execute SQL stored procedures", it is also a subinterface of `PreparedStatement`. For this reason, any CS implementation that abides to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) should also be able to execute normal `UPDATE`, `SELECT` or `DELETE` operations (anything a plain `PreparedStatement` can do).

The actual problem with your code is on the last line of the snippet you've provided; you're using [`executeQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) on an `UPDATE` statement, which doesn't work. Instead, you should use either [`execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()) or [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()). So changing that line into

```
call_state.executeUpdate();
```

should work.

If you want to do this "correctly", you should be idiomatic and use a `PreparedStatement` instead of `CallableStatement` – because you're not invoking any stored procedure. Additionally, you should take care of closing resources by using the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
        "UPDATE district SET d_next_o_id = ?+1 WHERE d_id = ? AND d_w_id = ?")) {
    ps.setInt(1, d_next_o_id);
    ps.setInt(2, d_id);
    ps.setInt(3, d_w_id);           
    ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
  // handle it
}
```